# Wordpress <img> Size Attributes don't match actual image sizes

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on an image-heavy wordpress project. I use the following code to set the image width and height for the medium and large image sizes, and set both to hard crop mode. These values are the same as the current values for Settings>Media: (code based on [this documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size#Reserved_Image_Size_Names))

```
update_option('medium_size_w', 335);
update_option('medium_size_h', 400);
update_option('medium_crop', 1);

update_option('large_size_w', 690);
update_option('large_size_h', 400);
update_option('large_crop', 1);
```

When I upload and insert an image using the in-post insert media button with the medium size option, everything works as expected. However, when I upload and insert a large image, I get the following markup:

```
<a href="http://saltdesignpdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/TCK7765.jpg">
<img src="http://saltdesignpdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/TCK7765-690x400.jpg" 
alt="_TCK7765" width="540" height="313" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-53" />
</a>
```

Note the `width="540" height="313"` part of that markup. It should be `width="690" height="400"`.

Does anyone know what's going on here, or some steps I could take to diagnose it?

**Edit**: I just tried switching the theme to twenty-eleven, uploading a new image, and inserting it into a post. This was the result:

```
<a href="http://saltdesignpdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/IMG_0729.jpg">
<img src="http://saltdesignpdx.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/IMG_0729-690x400.jpg" 
alt="IMG_0729" width="584" height="338" class="alignnone size-large wp-image-57" />
</a>
```

Weird. Changing the theme changed the dimensions specified in the img tag, but they still don't match the actual size of the image.

Comment: Do `size-large` and `large_size_w` and other `large` mentions have anything in common?

Comment: Yep - it's how you change the default image size properties in Wordpress (just overwriting them with add_image_size isn't kosher). See http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size#Reserved_Image_Size_Names

Comment: and how does the `class` itself come into play? Does it have relevance to `large_size_w` etc?

Comment: all the classes are just something the Wordpress media manager inserts to help out theme devs.

Comment: Have you gone through your actual files to see what matches `width="540" height="313"`?

Comment: The sequence "313" doesn't occur anywhere in my theme files.

Comment: that is really bizarre. Maybe it's the `540` and then resizing it proportionately to `313`? Have you searched for `540` also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was [content_width](http://codex.wordpress.org/Content_Width). Thanks, Fred, for the suggestion to search for 540 also.
After setting content_width to match my actual maximum content width, the size attributes wordpress provides in the `<img>` tag are now correct.